# Yii2 rest Method Not Allowed

Tags: yii2, rest

https://github.com/des1roer/yii2test

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

конфиг https://github.com/des1roer/yii2test/blob/master/config/web.php

сам апи https://github.com/des1roer/yii2test/tree/master/modules/api

как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://des1roer.blogspot.com/2017/08/yii2-rest-api.html

Блок с UrlRule должен быть выше блока ЧПУ